# How can I avoid overwriting of csv file writing the data into?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

```
for page in range(start,end+1,1):    
url = "http://wrf.meteo.kg/aws/index?AwsSearch%5Bid%5D=36927&AwsSearch%5Bdate_range%5D=20.10.2020+-+13.01.2021&page="+str(page)
handle = requests.get(url)    
doc = lh.fromstring(handle.content)  
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')    
col=[]    
i=0
for t in tr_elements[0]:    
    i+=1
    name=t.text_content()
    col.append((name,[]))

for j in range(1,len(tr_elements)):    
    T=tr_elements[j]

    if len(T)!=14:
        break

    i=0

    for t in T.iterchildren():
        data=t.text_content() 
        if i>0:
            try:
                data=int(data)
            except:
                pass
        col[i][1].append(data)
        i+=1
Dict={title:column for (title,column) in col}
df=pd.DataFrame(Dict)
print(df)
```

So I am scraping similar scructured tables from multiple pages and I did it but can not save it as csv file without overwriting How Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `to_csv()` method of `pandas`:

```
df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

- `mode=a` appends your data to csv
- `header=False` avoids that it was added to csv every time

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in csv library with the 'append' mode. Hope will help you.